# Prove that in an acute triangle the circumcenter falls in the interior of the triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

How can we prove the above theorem using synthetic geometry.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 7):

Suppose otherwise, that the circumcenter $O$ of $\Delta ABC$ lies outside the triangle. Suppose that $BC$ is the closest side to $O$. Let $CD$ be a diameter. We have $\angle BAC>\angle DAC=90^\circ$, contradicting the fact that $\Delta ABC$ is acute. Hence, $O$ must lie inside $\Delta ABC$.
[image]

Comment: But your diagram shows $\angle{BAC}$ already greater than $90^o$. You already have $\triangle{ABC}$  obtuse triangle

Comment: If $\triangle{ABC}$ is acute then how can you say $\angle{DAC} = 90^o$

Comment: It looks me proof incorrect.

Comment: Do you understand what is [Proof by Contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction)?

Comment: This proof is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Yes i understand proof by contradiction technique. I am saying your diagram does not have $\angle{BAC}$ acute. If your $\angle{BAC}$ will be acute then $\angle{DAC}$ also become $\angle{DAC}<\angle{BAC} <90^o$

Comment: Your proof will be correct when you take $\angle{BAC}$ acute then take circumcenter outside the triangle.

Comment: By the fact that your question stated, I quote, "Prove that in **an acute triangle**". Hence, I have already assumed that $\angle BAC$ is acute.

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: Hi @AnneBauval I am just asking the question which i doubt about his answer, I always encourage the answer.

Comment: Hello @IraeVid Yes you assumed angle is acute. I am just asking if you assume angle is acute then you will never find $\angle{DAC} = 90^o$

Comment: Please elaborate. I defined $CD$ to be the diameter, so $\angle DAC$ must be $=90^\circ$.

Comment: Hi @123, my comment was not for you but for IraeVid.

Comment: @AnneBauval My question is valid and complete in any sense. There is no need of further explanation. Question is itself self-explanatory.